# Filter empty values in DetailView

Tags: yii, yii2, detailview

Is there an easy way to force `DetailView` in Yii2 to ignore these fields in its `attributes` list, that for particular `model` are empty?

Or the only way is to define *every* attribute on `attributes` list with own function and filter empty fields inside it (sound like a little bit of madness)?

**Edit**: I thought, that this is pretty self-explanatory, but it turned out, it isn't. So, basically, I want to force `DetailView` to ignore (not render) rows for these elements of `attributes` list, that have empty (null, empty string) values in corresponding `model` and thus would result in rendering empty table cell:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define `template` parameter of *DetailView* widget as a *callback* function with following signature `function ($attribute, $index, $widget)` and this callback will be called for each attribute, so you can define desired rendering for your rows:

```
DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'template' => function($attribute, $index, $widget){
        //your code for rendering here. e.g.
        if($attribute['value'])
        {
            return "<tr><th>{$attribute['label']}</th><td>{$attribute['value']}</td></tr>";
        }
    },
    //other parameters
]);
```

Comment: Nice piece of code! Works great, only I'd consider `if(isset($attribute['value']) && $attribute['value'] != '' && $attribute['value'] != ' ') {` condition to "catch" more situations you'd like to filter out.

Comment: the filter condition is up to you )

Comment: Pretty cool. It seems to break some of the niceties like:

`'updated_at:datetime',` will just show the underlying value, not a converted value.

Answer (score 4):

Would something like this work better? It preserves some of the niceties like: `updated_at:datetime`, which with one of the solutions above will just show the underlying value, not a converted value.

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,

    'attributes' => [
        'id',
        [
            'attribute' => 'my_attribute',
            'visible' => !empty($model->my_attribute)
        ],
    ]
]);
```